regex to exclude lowercase only strings, but save strings which contain capital
Look to those regex
find /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/ -maxdepth 1 -type f |grep -v  [^a-z]+\.[^a-z]+
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/.mailmap
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/virt-manager
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/DESIGN.md
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/meson.build
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/NEWS.md
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/.gitignore
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/README.md
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/.pylintrc
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/.coveragerc
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/virt-install
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/.packit.yaml
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/COPYING
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/virt-xml
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/virt-manager.spec.in
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/INSTALL.md
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/meson_options.txt
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/virt-manager.spec
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/virt-clone
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/CONTRIBUTING.md
/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/setup.cfg

I want to get strings which contain CAPITAL letters, including .md .txt but only if words contain at least one capital letter, to explain better
CONTRIBUTING.MD OK
CONTRIBUTING.txt OK
CONTRIBUTING.TXT OK
Contributing.txt OK (has one capital letter)
hello.TXT OK (contain some capital letters)
contributing.txt NO (only lowercase)

I want to obtain this
  find /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/ -maxdepth 1 -type f |grep -v REGEXWORKS

    /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/DESIGN.md
    /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/NEWS.md
    /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/README.md
    /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/COPYING
    /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/INSTALL.md
    /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/CONTRIBUTING.md

how to do? Thanks

What about corner cases like Contributing.txt?

Contain one capital, so is ok.

grep '[A-Z]' will find any line that contains a capital letter.

This is already answered before

Should hello.TXT be selected?

yes, contain capitals

With awk and a regex:
find . -type f | awk -F'/' '$NF ~ "[[:upper:]]"'


Simply like this, using a glob:
$ find . -type f -name '*[[:upper:]]*' 
./virt-manager-5.0.0/COPYING
./virt-manager-5.0.0/NEWS.md
./virt-manager-5.0.0/INSTALL.md
./virt-manager-5.0.0/README.md
./virt-manager-5.0.0/CONTRIBUTING.md
./virt-manager-5.0.0/DESIGN.md

The -type f is to match only files.
If you prefer a regex:
find .  | grep '/[^/]*[[:upper:]]'

that can be better written as:
find . -regextype 'egrep' -regex '.*/[^/]*[[:upper:]][^/]*$'

Note: -type f isn't combined with -regex like -name does to match only filenames.

works fine thanks, but i like also a solution for grep if possible, just to understand better grep regex

regex way tried and don't work https://pastebin.com/raw/iY6ZEKAR

The find's way to use a regex do this natively. No need 2 pipes

Done a bit of testing, it seems that your commands match an uppercase in the path also. Although this isn't optimal, this seems to only match an uppercase in the filename (assuming there are no newlines in the filenames):
find . -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | grep -E '.*[A-Z]+.*'

The answer has been edited in the meanwhile

Tytrox solution is perfect, add as answer so I can vote please.

@elbarna Direcly filtering the filenames with find -name is without a doubt the BEST solution. One of the reasons is that after you start piping file paths you must start using NUL-delimited records

@Fravadona : you brought up a major fubar aspect of the POSIX committee - still allowing \n in filenames benefits practically no one while inconveniencing everyone.

Exactly @RAREKpopManifesto. As a end user and a professional, I never ended with a newline issue in my projects in > 20 years

My two cents
Before using find command, with -maxdepth 1!
Notice: shell could do this by himself!
echo /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/*[A-Z]*

/tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/CONTRIBUTING.md /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/COPYING /t
mp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/DESIGN.md /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/INSTALL.md /tmp/MG
/virt-manager-5.0.0/NEWS.md /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/README.md /tmp/MG/virt-ma
nager-5.0.0/virtManager

or
ls -dg /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/*[A-Z]*

-rw-r--r-- 1 user  4401 Nov 26 20:53 /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 18092 Nov 26 20:53 /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/COPYING
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 10438 Nov 26 20:53 /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/DESIGN.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  1108 Nov 26 20:53 /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/INSTALL.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 30648 Nov 26 20:53 /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/NEWS.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  1114 Nov 26 20:53 /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/README.md
drwxr-xr-x 6 user  4096 Nov 26 20:53 /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/virtManager

And you even could directly iterate:
printf '%-20s %-19s %3s %4s %7s\n' File Type Lne Wrd Char;\
for file in /tmp/MG/virt-manager-5.0.0/*[A-Z]*; do
    mime=$(file -b --mime-type "$file")
    if [[ $mime == text* ]]; then
        read lines words chars < <(wc < "$file")
    else
        lines=0 words=0 chars=0
    fi
    printf '%-20s %-19s %3d %4d %7d\n' \
        "${file##*/}" "$mime" "$lines" "$words" "$chars"
done

File                 Type                Lne  Wrd    Char
CONTRIBUTING.md      text/plain          125  611    4401
COPYING              text/plain          339 2968   18092
DESIGN.md            text/plain          140 1377   10438
INSTALL.md           text/plain           42  150    1108
NEWS.md              text/plain          679 4675   30648
README.md            text/plain           30  147    1114
virtManager          inode/directory       0    0       0


printf solution is very nice, even I get some format problem when "type" column is more little than other, try this command in a directory with one executable and  other files empty

With Perl and a regex:
find . -type f | perl -F'/' -lane 'print if $F[-1] =~ /[[:upper:]]/'

